# next-pwa not generating service worker files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I have a project with react.js and next.js, and now I'm trying to convert it to PWA app, using next-pwa.

I do every thing based on pwa-next docs, and when I run `npm run build`, it doesn't generate any **workbox-*.js** and **sw.js** files.

The next.js version is 13.4, and I'm using **page** routing directory.
And the next-pwa version is 5.6.0.

What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the nest-pwa version to 5.4.0, the run "yarn" or "npm i" and rebuild if still the same, remove the "^" in the package.json file so you only have "next-pwa": "5.5.4",, run yarn or npm i, and rebuild. it should resolve it.